# When I enter "npm start" , expo continually builds my package 20+ times in few seconds

Tags: react-native, expo

expo-sdk:37.0.0
expo-cli version is up to date

When I run npm start expo spams me with this :

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 49363ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 330ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 332ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 0ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 0ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 321ms.
Running application on SM-A307FN.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 459ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 0ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 330ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 0ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 484ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 0ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 332ms.
Running application on SM-A307FN.
Running application on SM-A307FN.
Running application on SM-A307FN.
```

I have not made any changes to my code...

Sometimes when I press npm start it rebuilds the the bungle 100 times and other times it will rebuild randomly and then rebuild like 10+ times ... xD

Any insight on why this happens ?

Comment: it seems like there is something on your machine that is constantly hitting the endpoint to get a new bundle. the suggestion from helodev Zcoder below may help. you should also try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop the metro bundler.
2. Exit the metro client app on mobile client. If Android, delete the metro client cache; on iOS, reinstall the client.
3. `npm cache clean --force`

Then enter `npm start` again.